# Laravel: route file syntax

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am beginner person in laravel.

I have face one problem. I have added below code in app/routes.php

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth_super_admin'), function(){   
Route::get('/admin/application/view/{id}', 'ApplicationController@viewApplication');
});
```

But `viewApplication` method is not run. is there any problem in my syntax.

Provide appropriate suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? What is the expected result of your current Routing? Which route do you want to define with your syntax?

Comment: My Laravel framework version is 4.2.17

Comment: oh ok - then my answer below might be wrong. 4.2 is quite old. Any specific reason for this version selection?

Comment: I want to access my view controller. right now when i am click on view link it will redirect to by default home page url.

Comment: This is a existing project so no need to update so...

Comment: ok - weill if if redirects you it seems to be the intended workflow. You apply the middleware and you are probably not a super admin. Therefore you get redirected. Can you show the middleware code?

Comment: can you please tell me where i am find this middleware code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144217/discussion-between-sam-and-frank-provost).

Comment: There is no middleware on v4 but filter. What is the exact error you're getting? What is the function declared on such filter `Route::filter('auth_super_admin')`?

Comment: YES, There is no any error message. but just my detail url redirect on home page. for example user detail link click and you go to home page.   i and new in laravel so i cannot provide you technical information.

Thanks

Comment: In route.php file i have add this if i am wrong then provide appropriate guide.
Check this image. http://pho.to/AhN5H